# Mirroring not working after a server crash

Tags: sql-server, mirroring, high-availability

I'm using SQL Server 2008R2. Last night, the host machine on which my mirror database was running basically went belly up. Thankfully the principle database was on a different host server and so was fine. However...

The principle is working but says suspended. When i try to resume the mirroring, I get an error in the SQL error log giving an error number of 9004.

A quick Google of this error number come back with [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2015753). (tl;dr: transaction log is damaged)

So, does this mean that the transaction log shipping between the principle and the mirror has somehow got screwed up? How do I fix this?

Is it as simple as doing a full backup on the principle and a full transaction log, then restoring them both on the mirror database with norecovery switch on and then set up the mirroring again?

Or will I need to do something more drastic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely issue is that the principal has had log backups performed since the mirroring session was paused and it cannot catch up, so re-initializing the mirror with a full and log backup should fix the problem.  First you will need to remove the mirroring from both servers with:

```
alter database [mydb] set partner off
```

Then restore the full and log backup with NORECOVERY and re-run through the mirroring wizard.

Comment: I figured as much, but just wanted to check in case I screwed things up. All working as it should now. Thanks.

Comment: we restart mirrored server and try replace backup but it not working.